# $watchCollection executes even though modelOptions to set to updateOn blur

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a feature similar to SO's "Questions that may already have your answer" feature. That is, when my form model is updated, I want to send an HTTP request to my back-end to search for any similar models already in the database before submitting the form and creating a new model.

Here is a simple form:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form>
        Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="resource.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"><br>
        Other data:
        <input type="text" ng-model="resource.data" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"><br>
    </form>
    <div>
        <p>Related resources</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="resource in relatedResources">{{resource.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.resource = {};

        $scope.$watchCollection('resource', function() {
                $http.post(apiUrl, resource)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.relatedResources = data.resources;
                });
        });

}]);
```

`$watchCollection` seems to ignore the `updateOn: 'blur'` option. Is there a way to ensure the HTTP request is only sent when the model is actually updated?

Comment: definitely correct on the 1.3 version...assumed you were using that one

Comment: I updated to v1.3 and everything seems to work fine now! I guess I was using 1.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated from AngularJS v1.2 to v1.3 and the code is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try the following format for watch Collection

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() { return $scope.resource; }, 
    function(newVal,oldVal){ 
        // do stuff here
    }, true);
```

Sometimes you need this function to piggy back on to get the update to work as you want it to with things such as DOM updates.